# How can I retrieve a facebook video thumbnail?

Tags: javascript, php, facebook

In the past I was able to retrieve the facebook video thumbnails with this.

https://graph.facebook.com/432400833863494/picture

That no longer works as of March 5, 2020

Answer (score 0):

The request format itself has not changed, but you will need to get your app approved for the **Page Public Content Access** feature now, if you want this for pages you have no admin access to.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#reference-PAGES_ACCESS

For videos on a page you do have admin access to, you have to use a page access token for the request (or that of a page admin.)